# Rails 3.1 not setting Last-Modified headers for assets? Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

How can I get rails 3.1 to set last-modified headers for assets?

Comment: Are you in development or production mode?  (Or alternately, are you precompiling or not?)

Comment: Both production and dev... and yes after precompile.

Answer (score 0):

You can set them through your webservers config, since the Rails 3.1 asset pipeline does not control it. The setting for Apache and Nginx are here under 'server configuration'.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html